# error on my view in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem in my project ASP.NET MVC 5 View. Here's my code:

[image]

**Controller**

**Index Action**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
   HeadVM list = new HeadVM()
        {
            data = new List<Heads>()
        };
        var AllHeads = db.Heads;
        foreach (var item in AllHeads)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                list.data.Add(new Heads
                {
                    h_id = item.h_id,
                    fname = item.fname,
                    lname = item.lname,
                });
            }
        }
        return View(list);
```

**View Model**

```
 [Serializable]
   public class HeadVM
{
    public List<Heads> data { get; set; } 
}
public class Heads
{
    public int h_id { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
}
```

**view**

```
    model IEnumerable<parishV3.Models.HeadVM>
  @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   }

<h2>Index</h2>

 <p>
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
 </p>

  <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>HeaderID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <td></td>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.data)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.h_id</td>
        <td>@item.fname</td>
        <td>@item.lname</td>

        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Add Member", "Create", "Home", new { id = item.h_id }, new { target = "_blank" })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

My problem is that I want to display data on my index view but when I write `data` it gives me an error before even in running my project.

Comment: Possibly error can be `@foreach (var item in Model.data)` here how you're initializing model can you post full view code?

Comment: @Justcode can u please check updated view code

Comment: @ninja: Yes, your `@model` is wrong like explained in the answers.

Comment: Change now your model and then it should work

Comment: @ninja it should work check patricks answer

Comment: @Justcode: Or the answer from brothers28. They offer the same solution.

Comment: Yes I didn't saw that one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
@model parishV3.Models.HeadVM
```

at the top of your View that it looks like that:

```
@model parishV3.Models.HeadVM
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }   

<h2>Index</h2>

 <p>
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
 </p>

  <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>HeaderID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <td></td>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.data)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.h_id</td>
        <td>@item.fname</td>
        <td>@item.lname</td>

        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Add Member", "Create", "Home", new { id = item.h_id }, new { target = "_blank" })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your model is a list of `HeadVM` (`IEnumerable<HeadVM>` in the message) while you are trying to access a property (`data`) of `HeadVM`.

Possible resolutions:

1. You have a wrong declaration of the `@model`. It should say:

   ```
   @model parishV3.Models.HeadVM
   ```
2. You need a second `foreach`:

   ```
   @foreach (var headVM in Model)
   {
       @foreach (var item in headVM.data)
       {
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: No he doesn't need a second foreach. I think the problem is that he has false initialized the Model in his View. Like @Just code said before

Comment: What doesn't he? That other solution is in my answer, right?

Comment: It was already there, maybe you didn't read it that way, but it was.

Comment: If it was sorry for that, my fault